# Proper technique for auto updating app

Tags: .net, security, auto-update

I have an app that has been in testing for a while now. The app will eventually be sold as SAAS although it will run a physical EXE on the pc.

I have a helper app that looks for updates and automatically installs updates if there are any. This used to work fine, but recently my code signing cert expired that I signed these EXE's with. I don;t want to get a new code signing cert just yet, as I still need to run this app in a further testing phase internally.

The helper app is reported as a suspicious activity when it tries to update the main app. This used to work fine and I think it is probably related to not digitally signing the apps anymore.

Currently, my helper app downloads the new version, closes the main exe, replaces the old exe with the new one, and starts it up again.

Why a forced Auto Update? The software is SAAS and there will only ever be ONE version (The latest).

The main app is not hidden or forced to stay open. Users can choose to close it, I just need it to always be the very latest version.

Is there any way to update app's automatically that is "not" considered suspicious?

I would like to implement my own code solution, and not make use of an existing 3rd party library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after some more research, I have decided to change my approach and inform the user of the update. I will force the software not to run if not on the latest version.

Comment: If it's SaaS, you can think to have ClickOnce deployment. That should ideally match your needs.